# Lightbox scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am implementing the following code:[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3afdptxu/)

Everything with the lightbox works fine. However when I open the lightbox it shows the middle of the content and I have to manually scroll to the top. I have tried to implement Javascript code

```
    $('#light').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){ 
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        return false; 
    });
});
```

However it seems it does not work. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that you didn't load jQuery. And Instead of using each, you can just write `$('#light').click(function(){ 
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        return false; 
    });`

Comment: I have tried it but it seems that this didn't fix the issue

Comment: Because you still didn't load jQuery. Check this article to learn how to load jQuery: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace href="javascript:void(0)" by href="#"

Comment: I have tried it but it seems that this didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

In your `.white_content` class **update** your `top:0` to `top:115px`
This may help you to put your lightbox without scroll to top

Comment: I have tried it but it seems that this didn't fix the issue